# How do I use keystores and truststores with Play 1.x framework?

Tags: java, playframework, keystore, playframework-1.x, truststore

I have a Java application that I'm trying to enforce SSL encryption with a custom certificate chain by putting the certificates in a keystore/truststore.

I've created a JKS keystore and truststore and placed the client and CA certificates in their proper stores. I edited the application.conf file as per the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.5.x/production#application)

application.conf

```
keystore.algorithm=JKS
keystore.password=password
keystore.file=conf/certificate.jks
ssl.Keystore=conf/truststore.jks
ssl.keyStorePassword=password
ssl.cavalidation=true
```

However, the SSL encryption does not work in this configuration. I have tried putting the certificates in the Java default "cacerts" keystore and this works, but this is not the preferred method of achieving this encryption. Any ideas on why the method described in the documentation does not work in this case?